# Is it safe to use @angular/cdk 7 within an Angular 6 application?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I currently have an Angular 6.x application and want to take advantage of the drag and drop implemented in @angular/cdk 7. I have already upgraded my cdk to 7 and the application appears to run fine.

Are there any risks to doing this without upgrading all Angular packages to 7?

Example package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "7.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.2"
}
```

Comment: why dont you want to upgrade to 7? there are very very minor differences. I don't think it will cause issue. But If you use part of the assembly from 7 and the other parts from 6, you most probably will have dependency related inconsistencies

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a requirement to keep Angular version under 7 for now. It is a possibility in the future. For now I just see the inconsistent dependency

Comment: ... the inconsistent dependency warnings on npm/yarn install.

Comment: If you don't upgrade you need to accept these warnings unconditionally. It is an unstable environment.